# How to auto destroy Zend session after a certain time?

Tags: php, zend-framework, session

Is it possible to destroy a session after a certain time ? ( for instance 30 minutes )...
I'm using Zend framework sessions

```
$sessionRegeneration = new Zend_Session_Namespace('sessionRegeneration');
```

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: Set the PHP session timeout to 30 minutes. The session will be automatically destroyed after the inactivity of 30 minutes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First set you expiration:

```
$sessionRegeneration = new Zend_Session_Namespace('sessionRegeneration');
//expire session namespace in 30 minutes
$sessionRegeneration->setExpirationSeconds(60*30);
```

after the expiration time has passed, the next time any request has reason to call `Zend_Session::start();` (which is called every time Zend_Session_Namespace is constructed)
The expired session namespaces will be unset.

The last command from `start()` : `self::_processStartupMetadataGlobal();` does the deed.

This is also the time when global hops expires are also unset.